# How to view file handling functions documentation using help function in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I'm trying to view file handling functions documentation inside Python Idle using `help()` function.

So far, I've done and got the following:

```
>>> fh = open('file.txt', 'w')
>>> help(fh.seek)
Help on built-in function seek:

seek(...)
```

How can I get the documentation?

Comment: @sshashank124 Well I can, but why the ``help()`` function not showing it complete.

Comment: I get ``none`` from ``__doc__``

Comment: help(file.seek) work fine for me. I get full information related argument using it.

Comment: @YousufMemon Looking at the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6370d44013f7/Modules/_io/fileio.c#l502) `TextIOWrapper` class's seek method has no doc defined. You can get the relevant docstring using other classes from `io` module: `help(io.FileIO.seek)`

Comment: @PoonamGokani OP is using Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import io
>>> help(io.FileIO.seek)
```

Returns:

```
Help on method_descriptor:

seek(...)
    seek(offset: int[, whence: int]) -> None.  Move to new file position.

    Argument offset is a byte count.  Optional argument whence defaults to
    0 (offset from start of file, offset should be >= 0); other values are 1
    (move relative to current position, positive or negative), and 2 (move
    relative to end of file, usually negative, although many platforms allow
    seeking beyond the end of a file).
    Note that not all file objects are seekable.
(END)
```

(Python 3.4.0)